# SSRS Tablix not returning full resultset

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a tablix that is only returning the first row from a created dataset. I verified my stored procedure and dataset in asp and it's returning the expected results. Also I read somewhere to check the count of rows using a textbox and the CountRows() function and it indeed shows the expected count. Is there any special setting in the tablix or somewhere that I'm missing? Also if I add grouping, it would return the first row from each group which are several rows apart. This is really frustrating. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid there might not be enough information to give a decent answer. Try deleting the table and creating it from scratch. Maybe the table got associated with the wrong dataset?

Comment: Or possibly the detail line got deleted, leaving only headings / footings?

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the row group it will do that. Or, if your row group is based on a single row value, that would be another reason. I had a limited result set coming back, and realized I was not grouping according to how I intended the report to behave and display.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there is a filter on the Tablix, or perhaps you are grouping such that it only produced a single row?  Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason I found for this issue is when a Matrix type of report (RDL) is converted to Tabular type of report by removing all grouped columns. To a developer it seems fine, but some where there is catch which does not convert a Matrix type report to Tabular and hence the grouping still continues and report never shows all the rows as expected. Only solution I found for this issue is creating a new RDL file of Tabular type and it all works fine.